# Problem with replying to an email

Tags: word-choice, email

I'm new here, so I hope I'm not going to violate any rule. I have looked for an answer to my question in the previous treads, but I didn't find any. If I didn't look properly, please, send me the link to the question.

I sent an email to a University in the United Kingdom to ask for some information. I started with the usual "To whom it may concern" and that's ok. I received a reply but I have to write again for further information. Now, the question is this: since the reply I got has been written by a person called "XYZ", who is part of the ABC Team, do I have to address the email to (mr or ms) XYZ or to the ABC Team?

Perhaps it is a silly question, but it is a real problem for me. I am not a native English speaker and I don't want to seem impolite or uneducated. Also, the information I want to ask for is really important for me.

Thank you in advance to those who will answer.

Luca

Comment: *Do I have to address the email to (**M**r or **M**s) XYZ?*  Yes - and note the capitalisation of Mr and Ms,

Comment: Or you can use the full name the way it was given: *Dear A.B. Cook* or *Dear Alice Bell* or whatever.

Comment: I'd also match whatever salutation they used for you - if their email began "Hi Luca," you're probably fine with saying "Hi XYZ," back, though you can stick with a more formal "Dear XYZ" if you prefer.

Comment: _Who_ you address your reply to is not really a language question, but... If the sender's email address looks like a personal one, I would address the reply to them. If it looks like a generic one for the ABC Team, you might address it to the team. Whichever you choose, I'm sure it won't make you look impolite or uneducated.

Comment: This question is a better fit with the provisions of Interpersonal Skills.SE.